# How to know if MKL is installed?

Tags: linux, bash, intel-mkl

I am working in a new machine, and I can't find the path to the MKL libraries.
Is there a way to know if and where they are installed ?
I tried `find -name`, but I could find nothing. Maybe they are simply not installed. But how to be sure?

Comment: Standard locations for non-distribution packages are `/opt` and `/usr/local`. But if you know how you normally install MKL then you might be able to use that to figure out if they are installed.

Comment: You can use `locate` command too. `locate libname`.

Comment: @Ric `locate` worked pretty well! It is a pity that it is not installed in all the cluster I work. Please, consider to propose your answer.

Comment: `locate` what? `locate intel-mkl`? anyway, the currently latest MKL 2018 release drops its payload (on Ubuntu linux) under `/opt/intel/mkl`

Answer (score 2):

Posting this here, just in case anybody finds this useful:

Because I installed Intel's MKL on Ubuntu 16.04 directly with MKL's install_GUI.sh, I found my MKL installation at */home/{user-name}/intel/mkl* .

Comment: Believe it or not — I did! It took me twenty minutes to recognize where the default install directory was on Linux with `install.sh`.

Comment: Which MKL version did you install on Ubuntu16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with `whereis <YOURAPPNAME/YOURLIBNAME>`. More on `whereis` [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis)

Generally speaking there might be a manual installation of some package which is not listed neither in standard binary locations neither in `PATH`.

In this case your only option is to do iterations over whole file system hierarchy and to check if a directory contains the executable file you are looking for.

Comment: Actually I have other option other than do iterations over the whole system. I can use `locate` as explained by Ric in the comments.

Comment: Basically the iteration is the WORSE thing that can be done, have you tried `whereis` command ? Surely `locate` will do the work too, but it will cost some performance on the system overall as it has to update its database from time to time, from the other side `whereis` will cost you reading file system whenever you want to find some lib. Basically what to choose its up to you ;)

Comment: yes, I tried `whereis`, I guess, as you said, some of the packages were manually installed, because I've got simply no result. If you knew about `locate`  and that "the iteration is the WORSE thing that can be done", why not tell me about it from the beginning?

Comment: well, truely speaking it just didn't come to my mind first, I think because its not coming with standard *nix boxes, wherease `whereis` is almost everywhere under the hand as a part of `util-linux` package.

Comment: But whereis what? What should I put after whereis? Whereis mkl doesn't work

Comment: @Caterina The argument to `whereis` is normally either a binary name or library name. If `whereis <YOURBINARYNAME>` is failing then, your binary is not listed in any of locations where `whereis` tool is looking them. The location are the standard Linux places, and in the places specified by `$PATH` and `$MANPATH`. For more info check the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whereis.1.html) page

Answer (score -1):

You can activatie environment variable of the mkl by

```
source path-to-install-location/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/env/vars.sh
```

var.sh has some parameter you can specific. Such as `source vars.sh intel64`.

And if you run `which mkl_link_tool` and get a result, it installed successfully